# Passing a property from a class into its state class and use it in a Text widget

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm wondering how I can pass a string from a class into its state class.
I tried passing a string into a Text widget using `widget.foodName` but it returns me the error "Evaluation of this constant expression throws an exception".
I guess since the constructor is declaring that string it returns me that issue.
Any ideas how to solve this?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class FoodCard extends StatefulWidget {
  @override


  FoodCard(this.chosenIcon, this.foodName, this.expireDate);
  int chosenIcon;
  String foodName;
  String expireDate;

  _FoodCardState createState() => _FoodCardState();
}

class _FoodCardState extends State<FoodCard> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {


    return Card(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: <Widget>[
          const ListTile(
            leading: Icon(Icons.apps),
            title: Text(widget.foodName), // <<<--------------
            subtitle: Text("xyz"),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `FoodCard` class into the following structure, and you'll be able to call `foodName` property without any problems. These changes are made following the `Stateful` widget class [documentation](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/StatefulWidget-class.html):

```
 class FoodCard extends StatefulWidget {

 FoodCard({Key key, this.chosenIcon, this.foodName, this.expireDate}): super(key: key);

 final int chosenIcon;
 final String foodName;
 final String expireDate;

 @override
 _FoodCardState createState() => _FoodCardState();

}
```

And you should also remove `const` which is added before `ListTile` widget:

```
 class _FoodCardState extends State<FoodCard> {
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Card(
     child: Column(
       mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
       children: <Widget>[
           ListTile(
           leading: Icon(Icons.apps),
           title: Text(widget.foodName), // <<<--------------
           subtitle: Text("xyz"),
           )
         ],
       ),
     );
   }
 }
```

Comment: Tried your solutions, receiving still the same problem.

Comment: Yeah don't know how the const slipped in there, working fine now thanks :)